# How to Apply an equation to a Pandas dataframe ByGroup

Tags: dataframe, pandas

Its that time of the day when I have been banging my head against the keyboard too long and I would appreciate any advice.  My over all goal is to ingest a datafile of hourly Temperature which has gaps in it.   I want to fill those gaps using a linear regression with Temperature from a nearby site.  But I want to do this BY YEAR and BY MONTH.  So with help from folks here I have been able to do much of this. 
Now I have applied a linear regression function BY YEAR AND MONTH like

```
Corr_grouped=DF_grouped.apply(lambda x: stats.linregress(x [Labels[0]], x [Labels[3]]))
```

This has produced the following which has outputs of slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err and displays like this.

```
> 2010  1     (0.806190897504, 5.75672188581, 0.901179913935...
>       2     (0.739906365408, 8.05204746237, 0.894050112908...
>       3     (0.773199101365, 6.88505178697, 0.898475211997... ...
>       10    (0.87497855294, 4.10227036556, 0.939948762031,...
>       11    (0.793072407801, 6.38604194806, 0.923659962858...
```

I have been reading all day by cant find and exact solution.  Now my question is how do apply this back to the original data frame.  I would like a new column in the DF that applies the linear regression y=mx+c to each line in the original data using the column 3 as the input BUT to do that using the specific coefficients (slope, intercept) that are different for each YEAR and MONTH.  Any ideas most welcomed :)
Cheers
Jason

EDIT:
Great.  So the DF looks like this.  It has timestamps every 30 minutes for multiple years.  It has gaps (NaN) that may be 1 or multiple intervals.  I need to fill in the gaps in the original column (T_original) using a relationship with a nearby station (T_nearby). But it is not a simple substitution.  The site is often some distance away and the temperatures are correlated but not the same (i.e. one may be 2oC hotter).  SO the T_nearby station has to be adjusted first then used to fill the gap.

```
                        T_original  T_nearby
2010-01-01 00:00:00  25.87873       25.4
2010-01-01 00:30:00  25.73089       25.4
2010-01-01 01:00:00  25.56144       25.4
2010-01-01 01:30:00  NaN         25.4
2010-01-01 02:00:00  25.24789       25.6
2010-01-01 02:30:00  25.17758       25.4
2010-01-01 03:00:00  NaN         25.6
2010-01-01 03:30:00  NaN         25.6
2010-01-01 04:00:00  25.07633       25.6
2010-01-01 04:30:00  24.99211       25.5
```

I want to breakdown the analysis by YEAR and MONTH.  So for each month of each year to calculate a linear regression fit between T_original and T_nearby.  This gives the grouped object above which has the linear regression parameters. For example year 2010 and month 1 the intercept is 5.75 and the slope is 0.806.

So I would like to apply that relationship back to all the Year=2010 and Month=1 to look like this.  Then for the rest of the DF apply the same approach for each month of each year.

```
    T_original      T_nearby    T_adjusted
1/01/2010 0:00  25.87873    25.4    26.2224
1/01/2010 0:30  25.73089    25.4    26.2224
1/01/2010 1:00  25.56144    25.4    26.2224
1/01/2010 1:30  NaN             25.4    26.2224
1/01/2010 2:00  25.24789    25.6    26.3836
1/01/2010 2:30  25.17758    25.4    26.2224
1/01/2010 3:00  NaN             25.6    26.3836
1/01/2010 3:30  NaN             25.6    26.3836
1/01/2010 4:00  25.07633    25.6    26.3836
1/01/2010 4:30  24.99211    25.5    26.303
```

Then I will use the T_adjusted column to fill in the gap in T_original.
Thanks
Jason

Comment: I don't think it's entirely clear (to me) what you are asking, perhaps it would help to provide an example DF and what you want it to be? Perhaps you want an `apply` which refers to `Corr_grouped` (?)

Comment: Thanks I just edited the post to make it clearer and give an example

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is to merge the grouped object with DF. To do that first create a common grouping column.

For the grouped object:

```
from datetime import date
grouped['common'] = grouped.index.map(lambda x : date(x[0],x[1],1))
```

For DF:

```
DF['common'] = DF.index.map(lambda x : date(x.year,x.month,1))
```

Now you can merge it:

```
merged = DF.merge(grouped)
del merged['common']
```

I am not sure what the exact formula for working out T_adjusted column is but now that the regression parameters are matched with T_nearby values it could be worked out with array operations.

To fill the gaps in T_original using T_adjusted:

```
merged['T_original']=merged['T_original'].combine_first(merged['T_adjusted'])
```